# Should debugging code be left in place?

Tags: debugging

Is leaving debugging code in place a discouraged practice?

For example, a program (written in Java) I'm currently working on can send emails. There are various ways emails that failed to send are handled. So in the method `send` in the `Email` class, I pass a boolean argument `boolean fail` which, if true, causes the method to fail. This allows me to test whether the emails that failed to send are correctly handled.

I have other instances of this throughout the program as well. Obviously, nowhere in the final production code will the program be told to fail. But is there any harm in leaving these debugging tools in place in case their corresponding features ever need to be changed?

Comment: Sounds like you rather have an issue with tightly coupled code.

Comment: Sounds like you need dependency injection and a mocking library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than commenting or uncommenting debugging logic, if you can set up your debugging to run based on an environment variable, leaving it in place is generally good practice.  It will come in handy for you (or someone else) down the road.  In the future you'd simple set DEBUGGING to TRUE to see your debugging logic, and obviously in production, you'd set it to FALSE.